# Draw logarithmic scale html canvas and javascript no libraries

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm really struggling with this project of mine. I need to draw a logarithmic scatter scale and plot data on it. 
This is the function that needs to be adjusted to my example ( see fiddle )

```
    for(var i = 0; i < maxHeight; i += axisStep) {

        // get normalized value, multiply with canvas height and reverse axis
        var y = h - myLog(i, maxHeight) * h;

        // show axis mark each 100
        ctx.moveTo(0, y);
        ctx.lineTo(30, y);
    }

    ctx.lineWidth=2;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
```

The idea is to build something like [this](http://www.atnf.csiro.au/research/pulsar/psrcat/proc_form.php?version=1.51&P0=P0&P1=P1&startUserDefined=true&c1_val=&c2_val=&c3_val=&c4_val=&sort_attr=jname&sort_order=asc&condition=&pulsar_names=&ephemeris=short&coords_unit=raj%2Fdecj&radius=&coords_1=&coords_2=&style=Long%20with%20last%20digit%20error&no_value=*&fsize=3&x_axis=p0&x_scale=linear&y_axis=p1&y_scale=linear&state=query&plot_bottom.x=50&plot_bottom.y=26) and data is taken from: [here](http://www.atnf.csiro.au/research/pulsar/psrcat/proc_form.php?version=1.51&P0=P0&P1=P1&startUserDefined=true&c1_val=&c2_val=&c3_val=&c4_val=&sort_attr=jname&sort_order=asc&condition=&pulsar_names=&ephemeris=short&coords_unit=raj%2Fdecj&radius=&coords_1=&coords_2=&style=Long%20with%20last%20digit%20error&no_value=*&fsize=3&x_axis=&x_scale=linear&y_axis=&y_scale=linear&state=query&table_bottom.x=62&table_bottom.y=34) the scales thus need to be logarithmic to actually view the data. My problem is now is too get the correct axis and plot them from the data 
I want to use the 'sumlogp0' and 'sumlogp2' field for the x and y axis to plot the scatter plot. Any ideas or tutorials or snippets that can help me?

This is my fiddle so far [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3L4humdv/)